# iterm2 node is not being loaded in a new tab using zshrc

Tags: bash, shell, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

when using Iterm2 I open a new *tab* and `node` is not being loaded.
I installed [AVN](https://github.com/wbyoung/avn) but I'm not sure if it's that's what It's failing or my *.zshrc* file.

This is how my *.zshrc* file looks like:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"

export ZSH="/Users/eloi/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

[[ -s "$HOME/.avn/bin/avn.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.avn/bin/avn.sh" # load avn
eval "$(direnv hook zsh)"
```

**1st Tab**
[image: 1st Tab]
**2nd Tab**
[image: 2nd Tab]

Any clue why node is not loading when I open a new tab or window?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh` show when you execute it?

Comment: ./nvm.sh

zsh: permission denied: ./nvm.sh @glennjackman

Comment: That was a stupid question on my part. Perhaps: in the first tab, what happens if you  do `. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"` twice?

Comment: @glennjackman thx, already fixed, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed, seems that there is an *issue* using `AVN` in mac BigSur with `Node v14`.
The following [LINK](https://gist.github.com/potench/c024f4499ba2f778d351d7d468daa842) shows how to fix it